# css and javascript files are not linked

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, webforms

Good evening everyone
I would like to deploy a web application (WebForm) developed with VS2017 locally on IIS but the css and javascript files are not linked.
I developed under VS2017, everything works perfectly well, but there I have no idea where the problem may come from.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It's not linked to your HTML? Can you show us your <head> in HTML.

Comment: Try giving us an overlook of your style linking markup to allow us to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

224/5000
Hi;

I solved the problem by activating "Static Content" in Windows Features ==> Internet Information Service ==>. World Wide Web Service ==> Common HTTP Features ==> Static Content.

thank you for all
[Static content Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZbK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using Developer Tools in most browsers (hit f12 when the page is up), go to the network tab and look what css and JavaScript files are not getting loaded. This will show you where the browser is trying to get the files from. You can usually make adjustments from there. You may have to refresh the page once you are on the network tab to have them reload.